# Create a new object using the inference rules

Tags: jena, jena-rules

I have a semantic network. Is it possible to use a jena framework to create a new object in the semantic web based on some rule. For example there is an object has a certain property, then you need to create a new object and make a connection between them. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you needs are reasonably simple you can use SPARQL CONSTRUCT queries, i.e.

```
CONSTRUCT { ?p :hasGrandfather ?g . }

WHERE {
   ?p      :hasParent ?parent .
   ?parent :hasParent ?g .
   ?g      :gender    :male .
}
```

will cause triples to be generated for stating grandfather relations.

If your needs are more sophisticated, you can achieve this with [SHACL](https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl/) for which an [implementation](https://github.com/TopQuadrant/shacl) on top of Jena exists. I will give a brief example. Assume you have the following RDF data:

```
@prefix ex: <http://example.com/ns#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

ex:InvalidRectangle
    a ex:Rectangle .

ex:NonSquareRectangle
    a ex:Rectangle ;
    ex:height 2 ;
    ex:width 3 .

ex:SquareRectangle
    a ex:Rectangle ;
    ex:height 4 ;
    ex:width 4 .
```

for which you define the following shape file:

```
@prefix ex: <http://example.com/ns#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix dash: <http://datashapes.org/dash#> .
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

ex:Rectangle
    a rdfs:Class, sh:NodeShape ;
    rdfs:label "Rectangle" ;
    sh:property [
        sh:path ex:height ;
        sh:datatype xsd:integer ;
        sh:maxCount 1 ;
        sh:minCount 1 ;
        sh:name "height" ;
    ] ;
    sh:property [
        sh:path ex:width ;
        sh:datatype xsd:integer ;
        sh:maxCount 1 ;
        sh:minCount 1 ;
        sh:name "width" ;
    ] ;
    sh:rule [
        a sh:TripleRule ;
        sh:subject sh:this ;
        sh:predicate rdf:type ;
        sh:object ex:Square ;
        sh:condition ex:Rectangle ;
        sh:condition [
            sh:property [
                sh:path ex:width ;
                sh:equals ex:height ;
            ] ;
        ] ;
    ] .
```

It will generate the following RDF data:

```
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

<http://example.com/ns#SquareRectangle>
        a       <http://example.com/ns#Square> .
```

which you can add to your RDF store.

This example with code can be found [here](https://henrietteharmse.com/2018/03/14/rule-execution-with-shacl/), as well as a more [advanced example](https://henrietteharmse.com/2018/03/15/classification-with-shacl-rules/).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible in Jena's rule system. Typically, we create such nodes using the `makeSkolem` [Reasoner Builtin Primitive](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/#RULEbuiltins):

```
[example:
  (?a urn:ex:owns ?b) 
  makeSkolem(?ownership,?a,?b)
  ->
  (?a urn:ex:hasOwnership ?ownership)
  (?ownership urn:ex:of ?b)
]
```

This will create a new blank node in the graph that will be used to reify the `<urn:ex:owns>` triple. E.g., when given a graph containing the triple `<urn:ex:a> <urn:ex:owns> <urn:ex:b>` as input, the preceding rule will generate the following graph structure:

```
<urn:ex:a> <urn:ex:hasOwnership> [
  <urn:ex:of> <urn:ex:b>
].
```

You can also construct URIs in your rule if you have some scheme for generating them.

## Java Example

Assuming that `so.rules` exists on your classpath and contains the rule from above, the following java code will demonstrate custom rules for this task.

```java
// Obtains a list of rules to pass to a rule-based reasoner
// These rules are read from a file.
// This is the most common case.
final List<Rule> rules;
try (final InputStream src = Resources.getResource("so.rules").openStream()) {
  rules = Rule
      .parseRules(Rule.rulesParserFromReader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(src))));
}

// Create a rule-based reasoner.
// There are multiple types of reasoners available.
// You may prefer some over others (e.g., when performing OWL inference in tandem with custom rules)
final GenericRuleReasoner reasoner =
    (GenericRuleReasoner) GenericRuleReasonerFactory.theInstance().create(null);
reasoner.setRules(rules);

// Create a RDF Model to store data in.
// Create an inference model to interact with.
// The inference model will store any added data in the base model.
// The inference model will store inferred triples internally.
final Model baseModel = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
final InfModel model = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, baseModel);
model.prepare();

// Stimulate the rule by introducing the desired triples to the graph
// :a :owns :b
final Property owns = model.createProperty("urn:ex:", "owns");
final Property hasOwnership = model.createProperty("urn:ex:","hasOwnership");
final Property of = model.createProperty("urn:ex:","of");

final Resource a = model.createResource("urn:ex:a");
final Resource b = model.createResource("urn:ex:b");
model.add(a,owns,b);

// Verify that the rule has fired. That is, that we have created some node
// and that the node relates our other two resources
// -> :a :hasOwnership [ :of :b ]
assertTrue(a.hasProperty(hasOwnership));
final Resource createdObject = a.getPropertyResourceValue(hasOwnership);
assertTrue(createdObject.hasProperty(of,b));
```